# How to connect 3 monitors into an Asus 9800GT

Tags: multiple-monitors

I don't know if this is possible but, I've heard that there exist some DVI connections that allow and recognize the connection os 2 Monitores in the same port (I can be wrong tho).

I have an Asus 9800GT 512MB on my computer that runs Ubuntu 12.04 and Arch Linux, and I am trying to connect 3 monitors.

I already have 2 (17" each), and want to connect a new one with 19", but on my 9800GT I only have 2 DVI connections.

Is there anyway to have 3 monitores extended without having to buy a new graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Do it right and just get the second graphics card. I don't know of any adapter such as you would need, besides there would almost surely be downfalls to rigging it up as such.

Those cards are not too expensive at all... do it right.

Does the motherboard have VGA graphics integrated?

If so connect the third monitor to the built in VGA (you can use an adapter).

In the bios set video graphics to the add in adapter. Both should* work.

Comment: I didn't know we could just connect to the built in VGA port, but doesn't it gonna use the motherboard GPU ? In this case an Intel GMA x3150 ?

Comment: Yes. The monitors on the 9800GT will use that cards GPU (and performace), and the monitor connected the the onboard graphics out will use the onboard GPU. So gaming on all three might not work. But using two fast screens and a third with a chatlog, spreadsheet or whatever should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, check what family does your gpu belongs. Fermi supports 2 displays at a time. So even if you were able to connect those, you will not be able to enable all 3 monitors at the same time.
Support for more than 2 monitors simultaneously started with Kepler series.
Also, you cannot connect to the VGA port of motherboard if Gpu is active, as display output is rendered through GPU.
If its a Kepler card, it should have more than 2 ports, you could direclty connect a cable connecting these ports. 
And yes, DVI -I can be split into 2 VGA outputs. You would need a dongle/splitter.

Comment: `Also, you cannot connect to the VGA port of motherboard if Gpu is active`. Incorrect. You can, and usually it will work just fine. (There are some broken firmware out there which hard disable the onboard graphics when they detect a dedicated graphics card, but those are the execption)